# OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError {err = 1282}

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyopengl

I'm trying to know the version of Opengl API that I'm using and I'm using this code:

```
import OpenGL.GL as gl

# Obtenemos la versión de OpenGL API
version = gl.glGetString(gl.GL_VERSION)
print(version)
```

And I have this error:

```
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
        err = 1282,
        description = b'operaci\xf3n no v\xe1lida',
        baseOperation = glGetString,
        cArguments = (GL_VERSION,)
)
```

What do I have to do to solve it?

Comment: You need an [OpenGL context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) to call an OpenGL API function. Usually, the OpenGL context is created along with the OpenGL window. Therefore, you must create the window before you can call `gl.glGetString`.

Comment: By the way, [OpenGL Error](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Error) 1282 means "invalid operation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OpenGL Error](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Error) 1282 means "invalid operation". You need an [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) to call an OpenGL API function. Usually, the OpenGL context is created along with the OpenGL window. Therefore, you must create the window before you can call `gl.glGetString`.